# Plot data in highcharts according to the timestamp of the data

Tags: database, plot, highcharts, timestamp, linegraph

I have a database that holds two columns. One is a 'count' field and another one is the 'timestamp' field of each count. I want to plot this data in the highcharts using a line graph. The x-axis of the graph is marked from 1-24 that corresponds to 24 hours in a day. Now the problem comes when the graph starts plotting. I want the timestamp of the count to correspond with the hour on the x-axis. So if the count starts from 14:00:00, the graph should start plotting from 14 on the x-axis leaving the first 13 points on the x-axis blank. But the graph is starting every time from 1. Thus not corresponding with the timestamp of the count in the database.

Can anyone help me out with this? I tried using data formatter and x-axis formatter, but couldn't figure out how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on how you have your xAxis defined - is it a 'datetime' or 'category' type?

Comment: set xMin:your mindata timestamp ,xAxis Max:your max timestamp

Comment: how your data and chart configuration look like?

Comment: You need to transform your time stamp into something usable. As @wergeld said, it depends on your axis type. If you want just 1-24 on the axis, it'll be easiest to use a standard linear axis, set your min:1, max:24, and convert your timestamp to a numeric 1-24 value.

Comment: @wergeld The x-axis is a 'category' type, not a 'datetime' type

Comment: @jlbriggs The x-axis is a 'category' type, not a 'datetime' type

Comment: Well, then, again - your category index is 0-23 (even though your categories will be 1-24). When you pull your time stamp, convert it to a number from 0-23, and supply that as your x value. The chart has no idea what to do with "14:00:00" as a value - it is meaningless. It must be processed.

Comment: OTOH, if you're data is not at an hourly interval, and you want the data to plot at the actual time it occurred (ie "14:23:46"), you will need to 1) use a datetime axis type, and 2) add a date to the timestamp, and convert to an epoch timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: Figured it out guys. Thanks a ton to everyone :)